# I cant load image in my spring mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using spring tool suite. I have placed the image file in folder WebContent/WEB-INF/resources

```
<img src="WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/team_pic1.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

This is my servlet.xml code

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/" />
```

I am getting error as

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) at http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCTest/WebContent/WEB-INF/resources/team_pic1.jpg
```

Here is my directory structure

[image]

PLS let me know where I am going wrong

here is the error I get when I run through browser

[image: s]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try:

```
<c:url var="imgUrl" value="/resources/team_pic1.jpg" />
<img src="${imgUrl}" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```

this build the right URL to hit the resource handler.

---

You also have to correct the resource mapping:

- if you want to deliver "subresources" then you need to add `/**`.
- Depending on where your resource files are located, you also need to correct the location attribute: I expect that `/WEB-INF/resources/` is the folder where your resources exist in the war!

So I think this it the resource configuration you need:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Content is (usually) served from `WEB-INF`, so it is not part of the path.

Your configuration defines the mapping

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/" location="/resources/" />
```

which says nothing more, that *static resources* are served from `/resources`, which means, they are delivered *as is*.

You could use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`- explanation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp77083)

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/team_pic1.jpg" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
```